# HP Laptop WiFi range problem

Tags: wireless

I bought HP 15-AC-122TU. I installed Ubuntu 15.x on my system and now having problem of WiFi out of range. When I'm near to router its come with weak signal but as come into my next room its out of range. Please provide us solution.

Comment: Most probably you have a weak router signal or your adapter is broken. Have your tried it with some other devices?

Comment: router is working fine for other devices.

Comment: If you have same problem while booting your device by USB, there might be a problem in your WiFi antenna (hardware issue). then you may take it for service center

Comment: it delivered yesterday i dont think their would be hardware problem

Comment: @user2897173 Have you checked from other OS's from the same laptop? Please try that too.

Comment: yes for windows its working fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to include result in terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly same issue. HP Laptop. Wifi works fine on windows. I think ubuntu has some issues with broadcom chip

Comment: update your driver by your terminal so that you can get rid of this problem